# Why can't I access instance variables inside block in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I'm using Rails 4, Ruby 2.1 and mongoid as my DBMS.

Inside my create method, I'm creating a fax object and sending it using Phaxio's API. I'm trying (unsuccessfully) to access attributes inside my `respond_to` block for various reasons. The `@fax variable` seems to be working, however the others aren't. For example, if the fax gets sent, I want to set the status (`@fax[:status]`) to "sent", otherwise I want it to be "draft". Setting it on the fifth line, outside of the block, works no problem. But when I go inside my block, and the fax gets successfully sent, I can't seem to be able to set it to "sent".

Also, I've tried writing it out differently - right now its `params[:status] = "sent"`, but I've tried `@fax.status`, `@fax[:status]`, and `fax.write_attribute(:status, "sent")`.

I've read documentation saying I should be able to access local variables from inside the block, so is this an instance variable thing? How should I go about this?

```
def create
@fax = Fax.new(fax_params)
@recipient = @fax.recipient_name
@number =  ("+1" + @fax.fax_number.to_s.gsub(/[^0-9]/, "")).to_s
@fax[:status] = "draft"

respond_to do |format|
  if @fax.save
      if params[:send]
        pdf_html, pdf_file = FAXMailer.save_pdf(@fax, current_user) 
        @sent_fax = Phaxio.send_fax(to: @number, string_data: pdf_html, string_data_type: 'html')

        if @sent_fax["success"]
          params[:status] = "sent"  
          format.html { redirect_to faxes_url, notice: @sent_fax["message"] }
        else 
          params[:status] = "draft"
          format.html {redirect_to faxes_url, notice: @sent_fax["message"]}
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @fax }
        end

      elsif params[:draft]
        params[:status] = "draft"
        format.html { redirect_to faxes_url, notice: "Fax saved as draft" }
        format.json { render json: @fax.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
  end
end
  end
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: check if ur getting `@sent_fax["success"]` this value and if yes then try `@fax.update_attribute(status, "set")`

Comment: @sent_fax["success"] is definitely clicking .  I tried @fax.update_attribute(status, "sent"), but that didn't work

Comment: Okay, I got it - you had the right idea, but I had to put :status in my function call, i.e. @fax.update_attribute(:status, "set")

Thank you!

On a side note, can you direct me to somewhere I can figure out why my previous attempts didn't work? Was I using deprecated methods or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry my bad, status should be a symbol, @fax.update_attribute(:status, "set")

Answer (score 0):

Sontya had the right idea, but I had to put :status in my function call, i.e. @fax.update_attribute(:status, "set"). On a side note, can anyone direct me to somewhere I can figure out why my previous attempts didn't work? Was I using deprecated methods, or maybe its a rails 4 convention I wasn't aware of?

Thanks all!

Comment: You was saying `params[:status] = "sent"` this just sets params[:status] to "sent", not updating anything in database

Comment: I had also previously tried @fax[:status] and @fax.status in place of params, are those just getter methods?

Comment: With this you was assigning a value to status but not saving it to db.